# AngularJS : returning data from service to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

I am trying to create a service to get json and pass it to me homeCtrl I can get the data but when a pass it to my homeCtrl it always returns undefined. Im stuck.

My Service:

```
var myService = angular.module("xo").factory("myService", ['$http', function($http){
  return{
    getResponders: (function(response){
      $http.get('myUrl').then(function(response){
         console.log("coming from servicejs", response.data);
      });
    })()
  };
  return myService;
  }
]);
```

My Home Controller:

```
var homeCtrl = angular.module("xo").controller("homeCtrl", ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$http", "myService",
function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, myService) {
 $scope.goData = function(){
     $scope.gotData = myService.getResponders;
 };
 console.log("my service is running", $scope.goData, myService);
}]);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should return promise from `getResponders` function, & when it gets resolved it should return `response.data` from that function.

**Factory**

```
var myService = angular.module("xo").factory("myService", ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getResponders: function() {    
            return $http.get('myUrl')
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("coming from servicejs", response.data);
                //return data when promise resolved
                //that would help you to continue promise chain.
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Also inside your controller you should call the factory function and use `.then` function to get call it when the `getResponders` service function resolves the `$http.get` call and assign the `data` to `$scope.gotData`

**Code**

```
 $scope.goData = function(){
     myService.getResponders.then(function(data){
          $scope.gotData = data;
     });

 };
```

Comment: What if I wanted `$scope.goData` to return data? Because if I init another variable inside $scope.goData and then make it equal to data or $scope.gotData, it would have been returned before it gets the valye

Comment: Not sure how this answer works, have used it and nothing is being returned into the controller [Gist](https://gist.github.com/wsfuller/4ca2b11748279a16c64dba0cb8032f81)

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for heads up.. I corrected my code now.. please check updated

Answer (score 3):

This is an example how I did for my project, it work fine for me

```js
var biblionum = angular.module('biblioApp', []);//your app
biblionum.service('CategorieService', function($http) {


    this.getAll = function() {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'ouvrage?action=getcategorie',
            // pass in data as strings
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        })
                .then(function(data) {

                    return data;


                })


    }


});

biblionum.controller('libraryController', function($scope,CategorieService) {
  
    var cat = CategorieService.getAll();
    cat.then(function(data) {
        $scope.categories = data.data;//don't forget "this" in the service
    })

  });
```